# Redux store, "Property XX does not exist"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to set up my first project with Redux, but struggle with the last details. 
When I try to use the stateProps, I get the error `Property XX does not exist on type (...)` when I try to access `this.props.isLoading` which is a property in the `Store`. 
I use React Redux and Router.

**EDIT:** *I have the same problems with `mapDispatchToProps`, but I only show the state props here. (Hoping that the solution for states also solve the problems with dispatch)*

Here is the related code:

**myReducer.ts in /reducers**

```
export default function reducer(
state = {
    isLoading: false,
},
action: any
    ): Record<string, any> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_LOADING": {
            return { ...state, earningHistorySolved: true };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Index.ts in reducer directory**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import myReducer from "./reducers";

export default combineReducers({
   myReducer 
});
```

**myAction.ts**

```
export function setLoading(): Record<string, any> {
    return {
        type: "SET_LOADING",
        payload: {
            testPayload: 1
        }
    };
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
class App extends Component {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <TopSection />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={StartCase} />
                        <Route
                            path="/cars/:carId/bike/:No"
                            component={Content}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
export { App }
```

**File where I try to use the props**, (error at `this.props.isLoading`)

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface IMyList {
    group?: number,
}

class myList extends Component<RouteComponentProps<any> & IMyList > {
    constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Button flagged={this.props.isLoading}/>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = function mapStateToProps(state: any): Record<string, any> {
    return {
        isLoading: state.myReducer.isLoading,
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(myList));
```

Comment: This seems more of a TS problem than Redux, the redux setup looks correct but in the definition of your component I'm not seeing anything for `isLoading`? Plus is it normal to return `Record<string, any>` for a function that returns an object? (spoiler alert, I don't use TS)

Comment: Within your `mapStateToProps`, can you do a `console.log(state)` before `return` statement?

Comment: @James: In `redux`, `connect` is a `higher-order-component` which it will makes `isLoading` available in `this.props`, provided if configured correctly

Comment: @Isaac yes, I'm fully aware of that - the point I am making is the warning (or error) does not seem Redux related at all. It would appear more to me like a mismatch of model typing i.e. the props definition being set via `Component<>` does not include a property for `isLoading` therefore when the OP calls `this.props.isLoading`, TS throws a wobbly.

Comment: In `mapStateToProps`the `console.log(state.myReducer.isLoading)` shows the correct value.. And the application is working, but I get errors when running tests (and in intelliJ), but this is then probably not an redux error, more a setup-error...? 
The `this.props.isLoading` is also the correct value, but as mentioned, I get the IDE-error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more of a TypeScript issue than a Redux one, I'm no TS expert but from what I can see you don't provide any definition for `isLoading` in your component definition.

It would *appear* as if you have just forgotten to add `isLoading` to your `IMyList` interface

```
interface IMyList {
  group?: number,
  isLoading: boolean
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the correct pattern is to add it to the interface? Wouldn't that mean that users of `<MyList>` can set the props..?
What would you do with `mapDispatchToProps`? I have the same issue there..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "users of `<MyList>` can set the props". In TS, the point is you define what values you expect so if they don't match the static analyzer can flag these up, in your case I fully expect that's what's happening. The fact you also have the same issue in `mapDispatchToProps` would solidify that because `Record<string, any>` I wouldn't have thought ties in with the object you are returning (a boolean property), I'd expect `Record<any, any>` would fix that issue (unless you want to be more strict in there).

Comment: My point was if someone use `myList`in another component, they can now write `<MyList isLoading=true>` and expect `isLoading`to be true. 
But this is not how `MyList` should be used.. The `isLoading`is supposed to be set from the Store, not directly as a property of `<MyList>`. Or?

Comment: @EirikO that's correct, and that's because that's how React works in general - there is no magic here between React and Redux, regardless if whether you use Redux or not, `MyList` is still just a React component that expects an `isLoading` prop. I _think_ you might find that `mapStateToProps` would override any props being passed in anyway so it may be a non-issue.

Comment: In addition to define the props in the interface, I also added the dispatch-actions to the definition as `setIsLoading?: typeof setIsLoading`